# Sum of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, summation

I have a question about the following equation,

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{d a_n(t)}{d t} \frac{c}{n}=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n(t) \frac{k}{n^3} $

is there any methods, analytical or numerical, that can be used to say something about the functions $a_n(t)$ ?

Comment: Look at the terms of the sums **independently**:

Comment: Strange suggestion to look at the terms of the series one by one, the hypothesis is not that, for every $n$, $a'_n(t)\frac{c}n=-a_n(t)\frac{k}{n^3}$, is it? That the sums of these two series coincide does not say much about each $a_n(t)$, I am afraid.

Comment: No, there is no hypothesis on  the behavior of $a_n(t)$ for every $n$

Answer (score 0):

No i don't think there is. For example $$a_n(t)=0$$ solves the equation for all values of c and k.